# Firebase Analytics integrated in the Android app as well as instructed in the docs but no data coming in the console

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

Firebase Analytics integrated into the Android app as well as instructed in the docs but while verifying using debug view my debug device cant send the data to the firebase console.

Under the Firebase project settings, 
integration > enabled analytic

1) Added dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
```

2) Creating an instance of Analytics

```
private FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
```

3) Inside onCreate initializing

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context);
....
```

Here is some logcat while debugging. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
11-20 01:36:02.613 V/FA      ( 1326): Connecting to remote service
11-20 01:36:02.716 D/FA      ( 1326): Connected to remote service
11-20 01:36:02.732 V/FA      ( 1326): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
11-20 01:36:02.910 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Logging event: origin=am,name=ad_query(_aq),params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=am, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_scre
en_id(_si)=-5418768155270587977, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-5418768155270587795}]
11-20 01:36:03.132 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Saving event, name, data size: ad_query(_aq), 94
11-20 01:36:03.133 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Event recorded: Event{appId='com.calculator.admin.ipcalculator', name='ad_query(_aq)', params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=am,
 _r=1, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-5418768155270587977, _dbg=1, ad_event_id(_aeid)=-5418768155270587795}]}
11-20 01:36:03.193 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 500
11-20 01:36:03.203 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
11-20 01:36:03.229 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
11-20 01:36:03.230 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
11-20 01:36:03.230 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 500
11-20 01:36:03.271 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Background event processing time, ms: 362
11-20 01:36:03.731 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
11-20 01:36:03.740 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Starting upload from DelayedRunnable
11-20 01:36:03.752 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
11-20 01:36:03.775 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Saving bundle, size: 626
11-20 01:36:03.792 D/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 548
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.calculator.admin.ipcalculator, 694,
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): batch {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):   bundle {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     protocol_version: 1
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     platform: android
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     gmp_version: 19000
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     uploading_gmp_version: 19629
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     dynamite_version: 0
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     config_version: 1572722121671911
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     gmp_app_id: 1:937890471059:android:ed33da1cfeac3ee8
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     admob_app_id:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     app_id: com.calculator.admin.ipcalculator
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     app_version: 2.2.7
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     app_version_major: 47
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     firebase_instance_id: e9dMQWQvKXo
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     dev_cert_hash: 628723216684240593
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     app_store: manual_install
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     upload_timestamp_millis: 1574193963741
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     start_timestamp_millis: 1574193962524
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     end_timestamp_millis: 1574193962524
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     previous_bundle_start_timestamp_millis: 1574193917020
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     previous_bundle_end_timestamp_millis: 1574193917020
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     app_instance_id: 440d8b97ac798285263f19f3ef638218
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     resettable_device_id: 1a9ad3e4-5a9d-4ba6-9e70-35e47447a658
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     device_id:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     ds_id: DSID=ADyxukvIrH1P-0rk2Yyq4qoEVacSFRoQa_OrRPUv1nGflOBLTjuHYUQkjxYalPFOaW7N3pu6yFnDVQKj61m_HgsHV1GyPQsuHWACIAk8emAE9
2w2MNYkPyA
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     limited_ad_tracking: false
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     os_version: 8.0.0
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     device_model: Android SDK built for x86
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_default_language: en-us
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     time_zone_offset_minutes: 330
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     bundle_sequential_index: 451
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     service_upload: true
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     health_monitor:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1573649132471
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: first_open_time(_fot)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 1573650000000
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1573649132471
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 0
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1574192423407
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: ga_session_number(_sno)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 3
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1574192423407
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: ga_session_id(_sid)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 1574192423
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1574193963750
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: lifetime_user_engagement(_lte)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 18739159
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     user_property {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       set_timestamp_millis: 1574193963752
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: session_user_engagement(_se)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       int_value: 1177079
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     event {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       name: ad_query(_aq)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       timestamp_millis: 1574193962524
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       previous_timestamp_millis: 1574193917020
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: ga_event_origin(_o)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value: am
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: _r
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         int_value: 1
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value: MainActivity
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: ga_screen_id(_si)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         int_value: -5418768155270587977
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: _dbg
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         int_value: 1
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       param {
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         name: ad_event_id(_aeid)
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         string_value:
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):         int_value: -5418768155270587795
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):       }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):     }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301):   }
11-20 01:36:03.795 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): }
11-20 01:36:03.796 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
11-20 01:36:03.806 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Uploading data. size: 641
11-20 01:36:03.956 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599990
11-20 01:36:03.957 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
11-20 01:36:03.967 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
11-20 01:36:03.967 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 3599990
11-20 01:36:03.988 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
11-20 01:36:04.015 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
11-20 01:36:04.016 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
11-20 01:36:04.031 V/FA-SVC  ( 2301): Stopping uploading service(s)
11-20 01:36:07.892 V/FA      ( 1326): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Alright, I've fixed the above issue. And the problem was in the Firebase Project while setting up the project at the beginning, APK should have to communicate with the Firebase project but somehow I pressed the SKIP button. Though other Firebase products like Remote Config, Push Notify were working fine.     So after complete the communication process of the Firebase to APK. Firebase Analytics is now working fine.   FAULT WAS MINE.  Thank you.

Comment: Where was specifically the error? Was it the google-services.json file?

Comment: If you have an older Firebase project then download and integrate google-services.json in Android Studio. Run your app in a device or emulator then press the connect button from the Firebase console. And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to enable the immediate report mode by using
 `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app your_package_name`

Comment: I run that line in the terminal to enable the device like debug device. Anything else.